# Cannot access 'element' before initialization in Protractor

Tags: angular, async-await, protractor, end-to-end

I'm trying to write end-to-end test for Angular application using Protractor. I'm attempting to create a function which waits for an element to be present on page before accessing it, but I'm getting an error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'element' before initialization

although I did require element from Protractor.

The function is in file `global.js`:

```js
const { browser, element } = require('protractor');

const global = function () {
  this.getElementAsync = (element, waitTime) =>
    browser.wait(() => element.isPresent(), waitTime)
    .then(() => browser.wait(() => element.isDisplayed(), waitTime));
  }
    
module.exports = new global();
```

And I'm using it in another file:

```js
const global = require('./global');
const { element } = require('protractor');
    
var someFile = function () {
  this.doWhatever = async function(sec) {
    const element = await global.getElementAsync(element(by.css('.some.css')), 5000); //error is thrown here
    return element.click();
  };
}
    
module.exports = new someFile();
```

I'm open for all suggestions/advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable name collision on this line:

```
const element = await global.getElementAsync(element(by.css('.some.css')), 5000); //error is thrown here
```

`element(by.css('.some.css')` is trying to reference `const element` instead of the `element` import from protractor, thus the ReferenceError message.

Try changing your variable name to something else and it should work.

E.x:

```
const someElement= await global.getElementAsync(element(by.css('.some.css')), 5000);
```

Comment: Yes, I completely overlooked the use of reserved words. :sigh: 
Thank you for the correction and reminder, it works great now!